# PDE with non-constant boundary condition: why am I getting different results for the same problem in MATLAB vs. Mathematica?

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the same PDE in Mathematica and MATLAB, [image: Laplacian of phi = 0] where [image: phi is a function of x and y] It has a Dirichlet boundary condition on the left, a section of non-constant Neumann boundary condition on the right and zero flux everywhere else. The non-constant boundary condition is defined by [image] where [image: mu is a function of x and y] was previously solved for and all other variables are constants. I have developed code for to solve this PDE in both Mathematica and MATLAB however, they do not produce the same results, and I do not know which code is incorrect.

Below is the full Mathematica code:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
e = 1.60217662*10^-19;
sige = 3.37*10^-4; 
sigi = 18; 
F = 96485; 
n = -0.02; 
c = 1;
pO2 = 1.52*10^-19;
Ie = -(2*F)*(c*pO2^n);
mu2 = -5.98*10^-19;
l = 10*10^-6;
y1 = 0.01;
y2 = 0.0025;
y3 = 0.0075;
meshRefine[vertices_, area_] := area > 10^-12;
mesh = ToElementMesh[
   DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[True, {{x, 0, l}, {y, 0, y1}}]], 
   MeshRefinementFunction -> meshRefine];
bcmu = {DirichletCondition[mu[x, y] == 0, (x == 0 && 0 < y < y1)], 
  DirichletCondition[
   mu[x, y] == 
    mu2, (x == l && 
     y2 < y < y3)]};
solmu = NDSolve[{Laplacian[mu[x, y], {x, y}] == 
    0 + NeumannValue[0, 
      y == 0 || 
       y == y1 || (x == l && 0 <= y <= y2) || (x == l && 
         y3 <= y <= y1)], bcmu}, 
  mu, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
bcphi = DirichletCondition[phi[x, y] == 0, (x == 0 && 0 < y < y1)];
A = (Ie - sigi/(4*e)*(D[mu[x, y] /. solmu, x] /. x -> l))/(-sigi);
solphi = NDSolve[{Laplacian[phi[x, y], {x, y}] == 
     0 + NeumannValue[0, 
       y == 0 || 
        y == y1 || (x == l && 0 <= y <= y1) || (x == l && 
          y3 <= y <= y1)] + 
      NeumannValue[-A[[1]], x == l && y2 < y < y3], bcphi}, 
   phi, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
DensityPlot[phi[x, y] /. solphi, {x, 0, l}, {y, 0, y1}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Phi vs. x and y", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

The code produces this result for phi:

[Mathematica result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ydLG.png)

And here is the MATLAB code:

```
% Define constants
e = 1.60217662*10^-19;
sige = 3.37*10^-4;
sigi = 18;
F = 96485;
n = -0.02;
c = 1;
pO2 = 1.52*10^-19;
Ie = -(2*F)*(c*pO2^n);
mu2 = -5.98*10^-19;
l = 10*10^-6;
y1 = 0.01;
y2 = 0.0025;
y3 = 0.0075;

% Rectangle is code 3, 4 sides, followed by x-coordinates and then y-coordinates
R1 = [3,4,0,l,l,0,0,0,y2,y2]';
R2 = [3,4,0,l,l,0,y2,y2,y3,y3]';
R3 = [3,4,0,l,l,0,y3,y3,y1,y1]';
geom = [R1,R2,R3];
% Names for the two geometric objects
ns = (char('R1','R2','R3'))';
% Set formula
sf = 'R1+R2+R3';
% Create geometry
g = decsg(geom,sf,ns);

% Create mu geometry model
mumodel = createpde;
geometryFromEdges(mumodel,g);

% Apply boundary conditions
applyBoundaryCondition(mumodel,'dirichlet','Edge',8,'u',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(mumodel,'dirichlet','Edge',9,'u',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(mumodel,'dirichlet','Edge',10,'u',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(mumodel,'dirichlet','Edge',6,'u',mu2);
applyBoundaryCondition(mumodel,'neumann','Edge',1,'g',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(mumodel,'neumann','Edge',3,'g',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(mumodel,'neumann','Edge',4,'g',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(mumodel,'neumann','Edge',2,'g',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(mumodel,'neumann','Edge',5,'g',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(mumodel,'neumann','Edge',7,'g',0);

% Solve PDE for mu
specifyCoefficients(mumodel,'m',0,'d',0,'c',1,'a',0,'f',0);
generateMesh(mumodel,'Hmax',l);
solmu = solvepde(mumodel);

% Create phi geometry model
phimodel = createpde;
geometryFromEdges(phimodel,g);

% Make sure initial condition is suitable
setInitialConditions(phimodel,0);
setInitialConditions(phimodel,-0.7,'Edge',6);

% Define nonconstant Neumann boundary condition
bcfun = @(location,state)(sigi/(4*e)*evaluateGradient(solmu,l,location.y)-Ie)/sigi;

% Apply boundary conditions
applyBoundaryCondition(phimodel,'dirichlet','Edge',8,'u',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(phimodel,'dirichlet','Edge',9,'u',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(phimodel,'dirichlet','Edge',10,'u',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(phimodel,'neumann','Edge',6,'g',bcfun);
applyBoundaryCondition(phimodel,'neumann','Edge',1,'g',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(phimodel,'neumann','Edge',3,'g',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(phimodel,'neumann','Edge',4,'g',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(phimodel,'neumann','Edge',2,'g',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(phimodel,'neumann','Edge',5,'g',0);
applyBoundaryCondition(phimodel,'neumann','Edge',7,'g',0);

% Solve PDE for phi and plot results
specifyCoefficients(phimodel,'m',0,'d',0,'c',1,'a',0,'f',0);
generateMesh(phimodel,'Hmax',l);
solphi = solvepde(phimodel);
phi = solphi.NodalSolution;
pdeplot(phimodel,'XYData',phi)
title('Phi vs. x and y')
xlabel('x-position')
ylabel('y-position')
```

The MATLAB code produces this as the results for phi:
[image: MATLAB result]

Which code is correct? Where is the error?

Comment: Before I concluded that those two plots are of different results I'd like to see the colour scale for the *Mathematica* version as you've shown us the scale for the Matlab version.  Without that I might just suspect that the *Mathematica* has a higher resolution along the z (or colour) axis.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark good catch! I've updated the Mathematica plot to include a color legend. Thanks!

Comment: I can't see it.  And no, I won't follow a link off SO to who knows where.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark when I went back to edit the question it said that because I am a new poster, I don't have enough reputation points to be able to paste an image directly into the question. Therefore, SO automatically created a link to the image instead. But if you won't click on the link, I will just tell you that the colorbar shows a constant gradient from 0 to ~-0.7 across the entire x-range, so the two results are in fact different and it is not an issue of resolution. You can also see this if you copy and paste the code and run it for yourself